# How to interpolate a graph with multiple series in Excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel-2007, charts

I have a X-Y scatter plot in Excel 2007 with multiple lines on same plot like a series for 2%, and other series for 3% and 5%.
How can I interpolate such data? For example, if I want to know a value corresponding to a series of 4% at value of 30 units (on the x axis) that is for X=30, what is Y for a series of 4%?

[image]

Comment: please share what have you tried so far and why that doesn't work? Have you tried trendline?

Comment: yeah I have tried trendlines but that is not what i am looking for actually. I want to know the value at some random value of X(say 30) for a series of 4% (one other than those that are already available like 2,3 and 5).

Comment: If you want to use it in a calculation, then look for `TREND` function, that may help.

Comment: The solution will depend on what you have to work with.  How well can you match a curve to the data (can you fit a simple equation to each dataset with a very high R^2 value)?  Do you get a similar quality curve for each dataset, and similar curve type?  Do you have actual datapoints at X=30, and how well do those points match the curve?  For example, if you have actual values at X=30 for the 3% and 5% curves, they lie on the curves, and the "spacing" between the curves is linear (distance between 3% vs. 5% is twice the distance between 2% vs. 3%, you can just interpolate those two points.

Comment: It gets more complicated from there.  For example, if the spacing between the curves isn't linear, you need to estimate the effect of an additional variable (the % value).  It would help if you added the actual data to the question (unless it's a massive amount).

Comment: weel you can say in my case i have 3 axis X, Y and Z where Z represents the series 3,5 and 7. In my case I want to know whether excel can give me a value of Y (through a function or any other method) if suppose I enter X=30 and Z=4.? hope you get the idea. And i have already tried TREND and FORECAST unctions but they do not give values for 3 data sets.

Comment: You can get to what you want, possibly using built-in functions, but it isn't a one-size-fits-all solution (there's no built-in function that will take your data and output what you want).  If your data supports certain simplifications, it can turn out to be easy. If not, it can be complicated. It all depends on your data, and it may take a little preliminary analysis to determine what approach is required. That's why I asked if it would be practical to post the data.  BTW, if you "address" comments like @fixer1234, the person will receive an alert to your post. Otherwise they will be unaware.

Answer (score 0):

export the data to python or matlab.
It would be nice if excel let you do that easily, but I haven't come across a method that is easily implemented.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).